# How to toggle hangouts

Tags: google-talk, google-hangouts

I'm trying to find an easy way to toggle hangouts on/off, but it seems it runs as a mandatory service, and the only solution I found is to disable it in settings/app, which is not very handy, and I think it reverts it to an outdated version each time.

Is there an easier/quicker way ?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: No, I am afraid it is not.

Comment: If it were, *Titanium Backup* could have been an option: it enables you to put a widget on your homescreen to toggle between "freeze" and "unfreeze + start"...